# python random seeding is deterministic, but it shouldn't be

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

From the manual:

> random.seed([x])
>
> Initialize the basic random number generator.
>   Optional argument x can be any hashable object. If x is omitted or
>   None, current system time is used; current system time is also used to
>   initialize the generator when the module is first imported. If
>   randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are used
>   instead of the system time (see the os.urandom() function for details
>   on availability).
>
> If a hashable object is given, deterministic results are only assured
>   when PYTHONHASHSEED is disabled.

```
user@MacBook:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Aug  6 2016, 02:11:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> r = random.Random('somelongstring' * 40)
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
332
>>> exit()

user@MacBook-Pro:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Aug  6 2016, 02:11:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> r = random.Random('somelongstring' * 40)
>>> r.randint(1, 1000)
332
>>>
```

The trouble is, i'm trying to get the same result everytime, but according to the manual and the PYTHONHASHSEED, i shoundn't be getting the same results every time. I've tried this on mac os, linux, python2.7 and pypy and they keep the same results over and over again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *default value* for `PYTHONHASHSEED` is to be disabled; there is no random hashing in Python 2 unless you explicitly enable it. It was deliberately kept optional in Python 2 to avoid breaking apps that relied on the hash being stable across Python processes, it was only made the default for Python 3.

If you were to enable it (with the [`-R` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-R) or with the environment variable) *then* you'd indeed see a difference:

```
$ python2.7 -R -c "import random; random.seed('somelongstring' * 40); print random.randint(1, 1000)"
955
$ python2.7 -R -c "import random; random.seed('somelongstring' * 40); print random.randint(1, 1000)"
277
```

From the `-R` switch documentation:

> Changing hash values affects the order in which keys are retrieved from a dict. Although Python has never made guarantees about this ordering (and it typically varies between 32-bit and 64-bit builds), enough real-world code implicitly relies on this non-guaranteed behavior that the randomization is disabled by default.

Python 3 also changed how `str`, `bytes` and `bytearray` objects are used; they inform the seed *without* using their hash.